# How can I make application update sleamless by avoiding the administrator password prompts?

Tags: macos, software-update, administrator, auto-update

I like to keep my applications updated but I find the update prompts intrusive and really annoying as they fail to happen during the night time due to priviledge escalation prompts which are blocking.

Examples:
- Visual Studio Code
- iTerm

I want to find a solution where most applications do update over night without any additional installation prompts.

Is this possible? how?

I do mention that these apps are not installed using AppStore, usually they are installed using brew cask but after this they have their own update mecanism.

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to mix installation methods - here homebrew and in app updates. Stick to one, in this case I suspect homebrew would be simler

Comment: Hoembrew casks has no support for upgrades, the problem is unrelated to brew, you can even ignore my mention of it. Brew upgrades work very well for cli tools, I use it a lot, but not for casks.

Comment: This question might have been asked almost 3 years go, I have the same request. Using [brew cu](https://github.com/buo/homebrew-cask-upgrade) helps me a bit,  but some casks have their own auto-update mechanism which requires a password. It is becoming really disruptive, I wish it would auto update in the background. Similarly how Mac App Store apps are updated, which I prefer over brew casks apps, but are not always available. @sorin, if you have found a way since '18, please share. :)

Answer (score 1):

From `man brew-cask`

> upgrade [--force] [--greedy] *token* [ token ... ]
>
> Without  token  arguments,  upgrade  all  the  installed  Casks  that have newer versions available in the tap; otherwise update the tokens given in the command line. If **--greedy** is given then also upgrade the Casks having **auto_updates true** or **version :latest**.

You can schedule a cron job to automatically run at set intervals. However, some casks may ask for a administrative password.